# Creating a nested loop to execute a function on a list of variables from a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, lapply

I have three data frames, that could be stored as such

```
dfs <- list("ibu_819", "ibu_1121", "ibu_1022")
```

and a list of variables for which I need to complete a very simple operation: changing all the 2s to 0s (an incorrectly coded dummy variable)

```
vars <- list("bene_lastyear", "bene_nextyear", "child_death","citychild")
```

I have done so successfully using this clunky code

```
ibu_819 <- ibu_819 %>%
  mutate(bene_lastyear = if_else(bene_lastyear == 2, 0,1),
         bene_nextyear = if_else(bene_nextyear == 2, 0,1),
         child_death = if_else(child_death == 2, 0,1),
         citychild = if_else(citychild == 2, 0,1))

ibu_1121 <- ibu_1121 %>%
  mutate(bene_lastyear = if_else(bene_lastyear == 2, 0,1),
         bene_nextyear = if_else(bene_nextyear == 2, 0,1),
         child_death = if_else(child_death == 2, 0,1),
         citychild = if_else(citychild == 2, 0,1))

ibu_1022 <- ibu_1022 %>%
  mutate(bene_lastyear = if_else(bene_lastyear == 2, 0,1),
         bene_nextyear = if_else(bene_nextyear == 2, 0,1),
         child_death = if_else(child_death == 2, 0,1),
         citychild = if_else(citychild == 2, 0,1))
```

I have always performed my data cleaning in stata, where I would certainly want to take care of this task in one tidy loop, but I can't figure out how to do so in R. I'd love if someone could show me how to do exactly what I have done by looping over the two lists provided above, and only writing the actual mutate function once.

(also open to suggestions for a prettier solution than my `if_else` strategy. I'm sure there's a more fluid way to change my 2s to 0s, but I just did what I did because I knew how.)

ALSO, I should note that I *do not* want to append my data frames just yet, so please don't solve this by combining the data frames and then looping through the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping data frames names as a list of strings is a bit odd, having a list of the dataframes themselves would be better.  That is:

```
dfs <- list(ibu_819, ibu_11211, ibu_1022)
```

Then you could use:

```r
for(d in dfs){
  for(v in vars) d[[v]][d[[v]]==2] <- 0
}
```

Note only the copies inside the list would be updated.  To copy them back into the main environment you'd need to use a named list and then the `list2env` function.  So the whole thing would be:

```
dfs <- list("iby_819"=ibu_819, "ibu_11211"=ibu_11211, "ibu_1022"=ibu_1022)
for(d in dfs){
  for(v in vars) d[[v]][d[[v]]==2] <- 0
}
list2env(dfs, globalenv())
```

If you want to do it using the list of dataframe names, (ie dfs is the list of strings you currently have) then I think you have to make a copy of the data frame inside the loop, then assign it back when you're done. This isn't good practice though.

```
for (d in dfs){
 df <- get(d)
 for(v in vars) df[[v]][df[[v]]==2] <- 0
 assign(d, df)
}
```

Finally, that pattern:

```
x[x==2] <- 0
```

Is how I would replace all the 2s with 0s in a vector.  Does the same as `replace x=0 if x==2` in Stata.

Comment: This makes sense, and the replacement code at the end is particularly useful. However, when I run the code you provided, it doesn't actually replace all the 2's with 0's in my original data frame. (ie.```table(ibu1022$bene_lastyear)``` produces a table of 160 1s and 234 2s. This might come down to your comment: "Note only the copies inside the list would be updated", but I don't exactly understand what you mean by that or what can be done. I think your solution is close to what I am looking for, but how can I make sure that after I run it, the original df updates?

Comment: My code first makes a list of dataframes, essentially it makes new copies of each and puts them inside a list.  Then we work on the copies that are in the list.  Personally I think its natural to keep them as a list of dataframes, but if you want them back in your global environment then you can use the `list2env` function.  I'll add some code for that.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying now. Ya, if you could include the proper usage of the list2env function to replace the original data frames in my global environment with the edited ones, that would be awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: I've added the code but I don't think this is good practice really.  If I had a set of datasets like this and I wanted to perform the same operation on all of them I think I would either do it to each individually, or if there were too many just maintain them inside of a list.

Comment: That makes sense. In this case, there are a lot of other things I need to do to each dataset that are not the same across each dataset, but before I can do those things, I need to make these edits across all three. So I agree that it makes sense to have them in a list as long as I'm doing the same operations to each, but only a handful of the operations I need to do are the same across all three datasets. What would you suggest in this case, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I don't know, it probably depends on how many datasets I had, and how similar they were to each other.  Keeping lots of data frames in the global environment doesn't seem optimal in any case.  As we've seen if they are in a list you can loop through them, apply functions across them or pass them all together into another function which will generally make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I should also add, that when I ran your ```list2env()``` code, I got an error: ```names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x```, but this was resolved by adding a line: ```names(dfs) <- list("ibu_819", "ibu_1121", "ibu_1022")```. This additional step strengthens your point that if I'm doing the same thing to multiple data frames, it is easier to keep them in a list, BUT its worth noting that this was a necessary step for me to use ```list2env```. I guess that the dfs weren't named within the list before.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `Map`

```
#create dummy data
l <- list(df1 <- data.frame(a=1:10),
df2 <- data.frame(b=1:10),
df3 <- data.frame(c=1:10)
)
var <- c("a","b","c")
#function to replace old values with new one
myfun <- function(df,var){
  df[df[[var]]==2,var] <- 0
  return(df)
}
res <- Map(myfun,l,var)
```

Here the original list of data.frame is preserved and all values =2 are update to 0 in the new list of data.frame, called `res`

Comment: You still need to select the column to be updated.

Comment: edited to consider the column to update

Comment: Adapted to my lists, I do this: ```dfs <- list(ibu_819, ibu_1121, ibu_1022)
vars <- list("bene_lastyear", "bene_nextyear", "child_death","citychild")

myfun <- function(df,var){
  df[df[[var]]==2,var] <- 0
  return(df)
}
res <- Map(myfun,dfs,vars)``` and I get the following error: ```Can't use NA as row index in a tibble for assignment.```. I am sure that the problem is with my data, not your code, but I am not sure what is going on here. I think I understand what you did, but I am not sure where the error is coming from. Any input?

Comment: Your data does not seem to have the columns you specify in `vars`. If you post an example data.frame from which is possible to reproduce your error, I can try to solve the issue